# Why can't I view an iPhone contact as Titanium Person object?

Tags: iphone, debugging, titanium, appcelerator-mobile, javascript-objects

I am simply trying to see the [Ti.Contacts.Person](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.Contacts.Person-object.html) object in my log so that I can see what will be sent in an XHR POST. I start with the following:

```
var contacts = Ti.Contacts.showContacts({
    selectedPerson:function(e) {
        var contact = e.person;
        Ti.API.debug({message:contact.firstName}); // successfully produces 'Micah'
    }
});
```

If I try to see the entire object, the app crashes:

```
Ti.API.debug({message:contact});
```

The error produced is: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: attempt to insert nil value (key: id)'`

I also tried to provide a JSON string to the debug method, but it is empty:

```
var contactString = JSON.stringify(contact);
Ti.API.debug({message:contactString}); // results in '{}'
```

Storing the `e.person.recordId` and then using this to `getPersonByID` doesn't help. Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: what does `contact.toString()` return?

Comment: No help. I don't understand why these objects are different, but Aaron must be correct. He usually is!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It cannot be done.

You need to pull each of the properties off of the object one by one to see what is in the contact object.

http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.Contacts.Person-object.html

Comment: So I guess that also means that I have to manually build my object to send via XHR?